# Simple Recursion confusion | Javascript

Tags: javascript

Learning Javascript, curious about why this logic pans out correctly?

Specifically why does `return multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1];` Why does it need to be multiplied by `arr[n - 1]`

**Non Recursive Approach:**

```
function multiply(arr, n) {
    let product = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      product *= arr[i];
    }
    return product;
  }
```

**Recursive Approach:**

```
function multiply(arr, n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1];
    }
  }
```

Both give the same result, as they should.

Comment: Did you try what happens when you use `arr[n]`? What arguments did you pass to the function? Did you debug (inspect, log) what the value of `arr[n]` was?

Answer (score 0):

The basic recursion logic is to multiply the last number with the product of all the previous numbers. `arr[n - 1]` is the last number. (arrays are 0-indexed, so n-1 is the last index.)

If we have an array like [3, 5, 7, 9], on the first call it will be like `multiply([3,5,7]) * 9`

Answer (score 0):

```
function multiply(arr, n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1];
    }
  }
```

ok, you want to multiply all or some element of array. i tell you don't multiply all elements, it is complex, first multiply from second element to last, and at last multiply it to first.

you do that:

```
x0 * x1 * x2 * ... * xn => x0 * (x1 * x2 * ... * xn)
```

ok, do that again:

```
x0 * (x1 * x2 * ... * xn) = x0 * (x1 * (x2 * ... * xn)
```

at every step, you seperate one element and go on...

at the end, you have only one element: `xn`, so you backtrack it and multiply to `xn-1` and you backtrack result and multiply to `xn-2` ... and at the end `x0`

hope to be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Talking about the recursive approach.
The function

```
function multiply(arr, n)
```

has the job to multiply the first n elements of the array **(starting from index 0 to index n-1)**

When you call

```
multiply(arr, n-1)
```

it will return you the product of first n-1 elements of the array **(starting from index 0 to index n-2)**

now you have the product of all numbers in the array **except** the last element that is **arr[n-1]**

what you do now is use that answer and multiply the element arr[n-1] to it, which basically looks like this

```
multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1];
```

it can also be written as below

```
small_answer = multiply(arr, n - 1)
complete_answer = small_answer*arr[n-1]
return complete_answer
```

now your complete_answer variable will have the product of n elements of the array, and it will return that as the answer.